# O(N) vs O(N + M) algorithm complexity

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I've seen both notations used when talking about the run and space complexities of algorithms, but I'm confused about the difference. For example if my algorithm reads two strings of length N and M, would the time complexity be O(N) or O(N + M)?

My understanding is that it should be O(N). In the case that the lengths are identical you would have 2N which simplifies to just N, if the lengths are different then when going towards infinity the longer string would take over and if we always call the longer one N then it's O(N) again.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the context of the notation O(N + M).

By convention (it is not a rule), when talking about the size of the problem, we generally use lower case letters like n or p. When using upper case letters like N or M, we talk about a **value** that influences the complexity of the algorithm, like in the [Change-making problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem) where W is the amount of money. The complexity of the dynamic algorithm to solve this problem is O(nW). But be careful, W is not of the same nature as n, and you can't simplify nW. This is what we call a [pseudo-polynomial problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudo-polynomial_time) when its running time is a polynomial in the numeric value of the input but not necessarily in the length of the input.

But you may well be in the case where N and M represent the size of the problem, and like you said, only the max(N,M) is deterministic of the complexity.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this convention? In what areas is it common? I've mostly seen lower/upper case letters used as author sees fit.

Comment: Let's say its an "implicit", never stated convention, a lot of books on the subject seems to follow it. Wikipedia seems to follow it too as for example in the Change-making problem page. Like any convention, no one will tell you you're wrong if you use upper case letters for size of the input. The important thing is to know what you're talking about and differentiate size of the input and value of the input that influences the complexity of the algorithm.